# Azure Cosmos Mongo DB Script to identify missing indexes

Tags: mongodb, azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Very simple questions. We have a serverless setup for Azure Cosmos Mongo DB. Currently hitting an reqeust per second issue and digging into the RU consumption. I'm no DBA. I know very little about Mongo DB. Inheriting this issue.

There are scripts like Brent Ozars First Responder Kit that can help you identify potential missing indexes in SQL Server. **Is there anything like that for Mongo DB?**

I would really like to not have to go through this legacy app and did through every query and try to identify the missing indexes. I'm hoping there's a more general way to knock this out.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent to Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit for MongoDB. Most of the MongoDB optimization practices revolve around monitoring, manually reviewing slow queries, and adjusting indexes accordingly.

Cosmos DB provides diagnostic logs that can offer insights into the operations that are consuming the most RUs.
You can set up diagnostic settings to send these logs to Log Analytics, Azure Storage, or Event Hub.
Once your logs are in Log Analytics, you can query them to identify operations that are consuming the most RUs.

Now that you can identify specific queries that might be slow or consuming more RUs, you can use MongoDB's explain method to understand the query's execution plan.

The result of the explain will give you details on whether an index was used, how many documents were scanned, etc.

This method is very useful, but it requires you to pinpoint specific queries to analyze.

```js
db.collection.find(<your_query_here>).explain("executionStats")
```